# How to determine perfect power for a decimal number?

Tags: c++

I am working on a question which checks if a number can be represented as a perfect power. There are solutions available for positive integer. I tweaked it to bit to check for negative integer. How do it tweak it more to test for decimal number like 0.008 or 49.49?

```
// Returns true if n can be written as x^y 
bool isPower(int n) 
{ 
if(n<0){
    for (int x=-2; x>=n; x--) 
    { 
        int p = x; 
        while (p >= n) 
        { 
            p *= x; 
            if (p == n) 
                return true; 
        } 
    } }
if(n > 0)
{
for (int x=2; x<=sqrt(n); x++) 
    { 
        int p = x; 
        while (p <= n) 
        { 
            p *= x; 
            if (p == n) 
                return true; 
        } 
    } 
}
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know, floating point is not exact.  Numbers such as 0.008 and 49.49 do not have exact binary representations.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. All your code is for integers. So why 0.008 ?

Comment: `0.008` is not a "perfect power of 2", like a "similar" number `0.125` which is, probably, what you meant. Note that just because `0.008` has a decimal digit `8` in it - it doesn't make it any more or less a "perfect power of two"

Comment: @Damien, yes the code I posted is currently for integers because I didn't know what would be the logic for decimal numbers. I want to implement it for decimal numbers as well.

Comment: @YePhIcK, 0.008 can be represented as (0.2)^3 so, why it is not a perfect power? Similar examples like 0.09 can be represented as (.3)^2.

Comment: @n.m. I guess OP means rational numbers. I don't know OP country, but in France "nombres décimaux" are a particular case of rational numbers

Comment: @n.m. are you even helping here? What you are talking is outrageous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is possible if you restrict your research to rational numbers, i.e. of the form `p/q` with `p`and `q`integers.

Trying to do it for non rational numbers has no real sense. For example, `2` is the power of `2^1/2`.

The first step is to represent yours numbers in such rational form, for example `0.008 = 8/1000` or `0.09 = 9/100`. The most efficient way to do it is to use continued fractions. You can find several posts on that subject on SO site. If efficiency is not much a concern, you can find such rational representations with a simple `for`loop. However, pay attention to introduce a margin taking into account rounding errors or errors in number represention. `0.1111111` is equal to `1/9`approximatively only. It is also important for the following that `p` and `q`are relatively prime. This is insured with the continued fractions method.

After that, you only have to use your method for integers on both the nominator and denominator parts. If you get the same power for each, then you can conclude positively.

For example, `0.008 = 8/1000 = 2^3/10^3 = (2/10)^3 = 0.2^3` or `0.09 = 9/100 = 3^2/10^2 = (3/10)^2 = 0.3^2`

Note: another method is to use prime decomposition of `p`and `q`.

Comment: Thanks @Damein, your points seems very much valid. I will try this, thanks again. I will mark your solution as answer, after giving it a try.